# Storing OAuth 2.0 token in cache and validating next request by compare it

Tags: oauth-2.0

We are securing our webAPI using 'OAuth'. All request comes with OAuth token in header. To validate the token, we use Identity provider's public key. All works well.

I have a question. I believe this is not the right (and secure way), but don't know why.

In place of validating it with the public key every time, we can validate it once and for next subsequent requests, Why can't we store this token in cache (with emailId as key) and for all subsequent hits, we can compare it with the token store in cache.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by OAuth token? Access token (OAuth2) or an ID token (OpenID Connect)?

Comment: By OAuth token, I mean Access token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on the character of the access token. If the token has a fixed life time that cannot change and its validity is verified just by checking its cryptographic signature (something like a JSON Web Token), then you can safely cache the verification results (if it brings you some speed advantage).

But access tokens are often revocable and it's necessary to validate them at the authorization server. The endpoint for access token info and verification didn't use to be part of OAuth2 spec, but it's in RFC now as "Introspection endpoint" - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662

Still, if there are many requests coming, even revocable tokens may be safe to cache for a short period of time (few seconds). But it depends on the character of your application.

Answer (score 1):

That's all fine and most Resource Servers would do exactly this. Typically one would calculate and store the hash of the access token for storage optimization reasons.

Note that you can do this safely assuming there's some lifetime that you can extract from the token and you will store the (hash of the) token not beyond that lifetime.